# PHP: no puedo insertar datos en MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Buen día,

estoy intentando insertar datos a mis tablas mysql, pero tengo problemas para insertarlo.

El programa trata mas o menos de un software para un Censo, en el cual se recopiarán datos de manera por cada ciudadano entrevistado.

Necesito insertar mis datos en estas dos tablas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de mi formulario **Frombd.php**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   
  <TITLE>CENSO 2020</TITLE>
     <H1><center>CENSO ESPAÑA 2020</center></H1>
        <H5><CENTER>Bienvenido, usted es el censado numero 
        
        
        <?php 
        // Caduca en un año 
        setcookie('contador', $_COOKIE['contador'] + 1, time() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60); 
        Echo $_COOKIE['contador']; 
        ?>
        
        
        
        </CENTER></H5> 
  </head> 


  <body>
    <CENTER>
    <H4>Datos Personales</H4> 

            <form method="POST" action="registrar.php">
            <br/><br/>
   
   <p1><label>Nombres:</label></p1>
   <input REQUIRED name="VNombres">
   
   <p1><label>Primer apellido:</label></p1>
   <input REQUIRED name="V_PApellido">

   <p1><label>Segundo apellido:</label></p1>
   <input REQUIRED name="V_SApellido">
            <br/><br/>
           
            <br/><br/>
   <p2><label>Edad:</label></p2>
   <input REQUIRED name="VEdad">

   <p2><label>Sexo</label></p2>
   <input REQUIRED name="VSexo">
            <br/><br/>


   <H4>Datos de contacto</H4> 

            <br/><br/>
   <p1><label>Movil</label></p1>
   <input REQUIRED name=" VMovil">

   <p1><label>Fijo:</label></p1>
   <input REQUIRED name=" VFijo">
   <br/><br/>
   
   
            <br/><br/>
   <p1><label>Dirección:</label></p1>
   <input REQUIRED name=" VDireccion">
   
   <p1><label>Provincia:</label></p1>
   <input REQUIRED name=" VProvincia">

   <p1><label>Municipio:</label></p1>
   <input REQUIRED name=" VMunicipio">
            <br/><br/>
            
            <br/><br/>
            <p4><input type="submit" name="data" value="REGISTRAR"></p4>
            <br/><br/>
   
   </form>
   </CENTER>
 </body> 
</html>
```

Este es el codigo con el cual hago conexion con mi base de datos **conexion.php**:

```html
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","censo");
if(!$conexion){
    echo "error al conectar bbdd";
}else
{
    echo "conexion exitosa con bbdd";
}
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Este es el codigo con el cual inserto mis datos **registrar.php**:

```html
 <?php
include 'conexion.php';
$VNombres=$_POST["VNombres"];
$V_PApellido=$_POST['V_PApellido'];
$V_SApellido=$_POST['V_SApellido'];
$VEdad=$_POST['VEdad'];
$VSexo=$_POST['VSexo'];
$VMovil=$_POST['VMovil'];
$VFijo=$_POST['VFijo'];
$VDireccion=$_POST['VDireccion'];
$VProvincia=$_POST['VProvincia'];
$VMunicipio=$_POST['VMunicipio'];


$insertar = "INSERT INTO cuidadano (Nombres, PrimerApellido, SegundoApellido, Edad) VALUES('$VNombres','$V_PApellido','$V_SApellido','$VEdad')";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);
if(!$resultado) 
{
    echo "error al registrar datos de formulario";
}else
{
    echo "registro exitoso de datos de formulario";
}
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Y este es el codigo con el cual muestro alguno de los datos **muestra.php**:

```html
 <html>
<body>
 <table>
 
  <tr>
   <td><b>Nombres<b></td>
   <td><b>Primer Apellido<b></td>
   <td><b>Segundo Apellido<b></td>
   <td><b>Edad<b></td>
   <td><b>Sexo<b></td>
   <td><b>Movil<b></td>
   <td><b>Fijo<b></td>
            <td><b>Direccion<b></td>
   <td><b>Provincia<b></td>
   <td><b>Municipio<b></td>
  </tr>
<?php
//COnexion BBDD///
$conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','admin');
mysqli_select_db($conexion, 'censo');



$sentencia="Select * from cuidadano";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $sentencia);
while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
?>

<tr>
 <td><?php echo $mostrar['VNombres'] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $mostrar['VPrimer_Apellido'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
 
?>
 </table>   
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Error que se produce al intentar registrar datos. Notamos que si que conecta pero no inserta correctamente los datos]

Por favor, si alguien pudiese ayudarme, lo agradeceria mucho!

un saludo chicos! gracias!

Comment: Los campos de la base de datos en tu insert son correctos? puedes verificarlos? Al parecer ahí reside el error. Verifica realizando el mismo insert directamente en mysql

Comment: En `registrar.php` hay un typo. Dice `$insertar = "INSERT INTO cuidadano..."`, debe ser **ciudadano**. Además en Frombd.php algunos campos `input name=""`, comienzan con espacio, posiblemente eso cause problemas.

Comment: Tienes un error de tipografía como dice @aeportugal ciudadano en lugar de "cuidadano".

Comment: he comprobado los nombres en la base de datos y aparentemente está todo en orden. Con respecto a los espaciados, los he corregido y el fallo continúa. Gracias chicos, si saben de algo mas que pueda causar el problema me comentar porfa! Sería de mucha ayuda

Comment: En muestra.php haces una conexión a la base de datos diferente a la de `conexion.php`. Y ya que creaste un archivo para conexión, recomiendo incluirlo (`include` o `require`) para centralizar esto, tal como hiciste en registrar.php. Adicional tienes otro typo en **muestra.php**: `$sentencia="Select * from cuidadano";` Una vez más, debe ser **ciudadano**.

Comment: vale, pero mi preocupacion en parte es el no poder insertar datos en la tabla. no comprendo porque no funciona. Me podrían explicar un poco como debería ir?

Comment: He comprobado que si pueda añadir datos mediante consulta desde phpmyadmin y si que me añade la consulta pero, con el programa no.

Answer (score 0):

Este es el archivo de conexión que nos has pasado:

```
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","censo");
if(!$conexion){
    echo "error al conectar bbdd";
}else
{
    echo "conexion exitosa con bbdd";
}
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Fíjate que estas cerrando la conexión, haya ido bien o mal. Deberías eliminar esa línea, ya que luego estas intentando usar la conexión para hacer insert de los datos.

Saludos!